# Restoring a DynamoDB Table to a Point in Time to other AWS Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3, import, amazon-dynamodb

How can I export data from `Amazon DynamoDB` table on **Account A** and import them to the identical table (with the same `partition key`) on **Account B**.

I would like to use a new feature described here [New – Export Amazon DynamoDB Table Data to Your Data Lake in Amazon S3, No Code Writing Required](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-export-amazon-dynamodb-table-data-to-data-lake-amazon-s3/)

I was able to write `PowerShell script` (with [AWS Tools for Powershell](https://aws.amazon.com/powershell/)) and export data from `Amazon DynamoDb` table to `Amazon S3`.

```
Export-DDBTableToPointInTime -TableArn $dynamoDbTableArn  -S3Bucket $s3Bucket  -ExportFormat DYNAMODB_JSON
```

Is there any possibility to import that data directly to **Account B** or I rather have to do it manually with simple write to `Amazon DynamoDB`?

Answer (score 1):

Since you talked about using the export to S3 feature, for now, you'd have to do it manually or use something like AWS Glue or EMR to get data from the S3 bucket after you use the export feature and insert it into a new table in the other account.

Another option is to just [use AWS Glue for the whole thing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-dynamo-db-cross-account.html).